# Getting key without enter on OSX

Tags: c

Please make sure you are using **OSX!**

gcc info:

Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~28/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~28/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)

I am trying to get a char from keypress and display it. I am trying to do this without the Curses library (will be used for Android and OSX among others and I don't feel like porting). Based on another post I came up with the following....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

static char ch;
void getkey() {
  struct termios orig_term_attr;
  struct termios new_term_attr;

  /* set the terminal to raw mode */
  tcgetattr(fileno(stdin), &orig_term_attr);
  memcpy(&new_term_attr, &orig_term_attr, sizeof(struct termios));
  new_term_attr.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO|ICANON);
  new_term_attr.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
  new_term_attr.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
  tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &new_term_attr);

  /* read a character from the stdin stream without blocking */
  /*   returns EOF (-1) if no character is available */
  char test = fgetc(stdin); 
  if(test != -1)
    printf("Value is : %c \n",test);
  ch = test;
  /* restore the original terminal attributes */
  tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &orig_term_attr);
}

int main()
{
  do
  {
    getkey();
    int ch2 = (int) ch;
    if(ch2 != -1){
      printf("%c \n",ch);
  }
  }while(1==1);
}
```

But this doesn't seem to clear the buffer so when I type a then b the c I see...

> aababc

This is currently being compiled and run on My OSX box with the commands gcc tect.c and ./a.out

I would like it to be abc

Comment: What you see does not make much sense... You have two `printf` statements that both put a space and a carriage return. How could you have such an output by typing "abc"?

Comment: If you "don't feel like porting", writing very system-specific code is probably not the way to go.

Comment: I am not trying to write system-specific code, I would be willing to accept an answer that is more generic. This is just all I have been able to come up with so far. The ultimate goal is as the question asks to capture keypresses at real time on any platform. Feel free to answer with code that doesn't resemble mine. My putting OSX in the title was purely because I knew it worked on ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works but you print the character twice:

```
printf("Value is : %c \n",test);
printf("%c \n",ch);
```

I've tried myself:

```
Value is : a 
a 
Value is : b 
b 
Value is : c 
c 
Value is : d 
d
```

By the way, you should not use a global variable but return the key instead...

Comment: Debian Linux with gcc 4.7. What exactly do you have when you type "abc"? You have something different than me?

Comment: One sec because I am seeing something weird right now anyway one sec

Comment: Yeah on OSX this freaks out let me port to Android and see if I see the same response might take a minute though.

Comment: So I don't see my value at all (which is part of the weird part) the other part is it does seem to reset sometimes on enter commands. Here is an example of output (notice I don't see the newline either)~/tmp/kid$ ./a.out 
aasasdasdasasdasdasdasdsasdasdsaasdasdsakasdasdsakhdsasdasdsakhdskasdasdsakhdskaasdasdsakhdskahdasdasdsakhdskahdkashasdasdsakhdskahdkash
asdasdsakhdskahdkash
adasdasdsakhdskahdkash
ad
asdasdsakhdskahdkash
ad

asasdasdsakhdskahdkash
ad

asd

Comment: Nice. If you type nothing, what do you have? Have you tried to fflush(stdin) before anything?

Comment: No should I try it each time getKey is called?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32694/discussion-between-maxime-and-jackie)